# Dynamic-Imports via babel-register resulting in surplus "default module"

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, node-modules, dynamic-import

I have (polymorphic) code that is bundled using webpack including dynamic-imports (for code-splitting) and want to run the same code in NodeJS, currently using *babel-register* to be able to run the ES6 code.

I've encountered an issue when it comes to the dynamic imports: The resolved/loaded module seems to be wrapped in an additional (default-)module.

The following is a minimal example, using `NodeJS v10.14.1`, `@babel/core@7.2.2`, `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import@7.2.0`, `@babel/preset-env@7.3.1`, `@babel/register@7.0.0`:

`index.js`:

```
require('@babel/register')({
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import'
  ]
})

require('./main').run()
```

`dep.js`:

```
export const bar = 3;
```

`main.js`:

```
import * as syncMod from './dep'

export function run() {
    console.log(syncMod)

    import('./dep').then(mod => console.log(mod))
}
```

Running this via `node --experimental-modules index.js` yields:

```
{ bar: 3 } // the syncMod
[Module] { default: { bar: 3 } } // the dynamically loaded
```

The "normal" import works as expected and directly gives the object with the exports. The dynamic-import does this too (as I would expect) in the bundled browser-version, but returns this `[Module] { default: .. }` thing around it in NodeJS.

Running without the *babel-register* code and rather using *babel-node* (`@babel/node@7.2.2`) (`npx babel-node --experimental-modules --plugins=@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import --presets=@babel/preset-env index`) yields the same result.

I need to run it with the experimental flag, otherwise the dynamic import did not work at all (`Not supported` Error thrown).

I could access the dynamically-loaded module without further problems by accessing it below the added layer like `mod.default.bar`, but then my code would differ for browser and NodeJS.

I'm grateful for any explanation for this behaviour and maybe a solution (/where I went wrong) to get the normal/expected exports object.

---

I'm currently using this helper as a workaround:

```
function lazyImport(promise) {
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    // Browser
    return promise
  }

  // Node
  return promise.then(mod => mod.default)
}
```

and wrap every `import()` like this:

```
lazyImport(import('./path/to/mod')).then(mod => /* use the mod */)
```

Comment: It's weird that ES modules *have* support, but it doesn't work as it should. This makes no sense.

Comment: Do you think it's a bug? Where would this need to be reported, NodeJS or Babel? I was thinking it may be something with *babel-register*, as far as I know it patches/modifies the native `require` implementation to transpile the code?

Comment: Have you tried this without `@babel/register`?

Comment: You're using `--experimental-modules` but none of your files are `.mjs` files, so you're not actually using Node's experimental modules.

Comment: I have tried it with `@babel/node` instead (edited that paragraph into the question) for the same result. The files are just `.js`, correct, as it was primarily written for only being bundled by webpack. I was hoping that babel (somehow) takes care of it, but thanks, will try with `.mjs`.

Comment: Indeed using `.mjs` gives the expected module-object without the additional Module around it. With a little adjustment to the webpack rules it also still worked in the bundled version. However it seems I cannot `require`/ES6-`import` other dependencies from within this `.mjs` file? I feel like it is either using ESModules for everything or not at all, is it? 
Right now the errors I got indicate bigger changes are necessary, so I'm gonna rather stick with my current "hack". 
The scope of this question is probably resolved though with the `.mjs` hint, so if you want to add it as an answer..

Comment: To give some insight: I'm just using dynamic-imports at 1 layer to import certain Components async / when needed. These Components of course have child dependencies imported "sync", so webpack makes one chunk out of it, which is fine. I don't want to refactor the whole app to dynamic-imports for every so little dependency just to make it work in NodeJS too for SSR.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Nice catch. Didn't see that.